# BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast - SMS Receiver

Tags: android

I know there are a LOT of posts like this, but none helped me...

My manifest declaration:

```
        <receiver android:name="com.myapp.SMSReciever">
            <intent-filter android:priority="99999999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

SMSReciever.java

```
public class SMSReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if ( extras == null ) {
            return;
        }

        Debug.log("launched..");
        abortBroadcast();

        ... huge block of code ...

            if ( a lot of bools are true ) {
                 this.clearAbortBroadcast();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

And YES, I have the permission to `RECEIVE_SMS`

edit: 
added the logcat if it helps to debug the issue:

```
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028): BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028): java.lang.RuntimeException: BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at android.content.BroadcastReceiver.checkSynchronousHint(BroadcastReceiver.java:451)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at android.content.BroadcastReceiver.abortBroadcast(BroadcastReceiver.java:374)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at com.android.systemSettings.SMSReciever.onReceive(SMSReciever.java:27)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1915)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:989)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
09-10 16:27:30.369: E/BroadcastReceiver(25028):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved!

The code is allright, but I was using an app called SMS Emulator which caused this error. According to the docs:

abortBroadcast:
    Sets the flag indicating that this receiver should abort the current broadcast; only works with broadcasts sent through `Context.sendOrderedBroadcast.` - notice this.

And it seems that the app doesnt launch an ordered broadcast, thus the exception is thrown.