# BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast error

Tags: android, eclipse, broadcastreceiver

I have two broadcast receiver. one for sms and one for call.
I confront this error. i see this page:
[BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast - SMS Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722206/broadcastreceiver-trying-to-return-result-during-a-non-ordered-broadcast-sms-r)

but I don't how ti use that suggestion.
Context.sendOrderedBroadcast. 
and if this is helpful or not. I have other receiver in this package for sms this receiver work fine. but this one doesn't work.

```
public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 Context context = null;
 SharedPreferences preferences = null ;
    Boolean  blacklist;
    Boolean  contact;
    Boolean  all;



 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


     preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("modes",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

     if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) { 

           String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);





if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

          if (preferences.getBoolean("all", true)){ 
                     Log.i("all", ":  " + phoneNumber);
                     abortBroadcast();

                     Log.i("block: ", phoneNumber);

          }

           else      if (preferences.getBoolean("blacklist", true)){
                     boolean str=Search.search(phoneNumber);
                     if (phoneNumber != null && str ==true) {
                     abortBroadcast();}}




           else     if (preferences.getBoolean("c", true)&&getDetails(phoneNumber)){
                     abortBroadcast();}





           else     if (preferences.getBoolean("g", true)){
                    boolean str=SearchInWhiteList.search(phoneNumber);
                    if (phoneNumber != null && str ==true) {
                    abortBroadcast();}}




            else      if (preferences.getBoolean("b", true)){
                         abortBroadcast();}





            else {}
            }

        }

 }
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="blocker.activity"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" /> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity

        android:name=".FirstPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<receiver android:name=".SmsFilter" android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter android:priority="999">


    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    <action android:name="bloker.activity.android.action.broadcast"/> 
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name=".PhoneCallReceiver" android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter android:priority="999">


    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    <action android:name="bloker.activity.android.action.broadcast"/> 
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>

    <activity

        android:name=".Search"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

    <activity

        android:name=".BlockActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".SmsFilter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".CustomAdapter"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name=".Setting"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".GetAllContact"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name=".WhiteList"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

edit:
broadcastreceiver fro incoming call to android phone is non-ordering. so that cant be aborted using above code. my question is that how can we handle this kind of broadcast?
I know that using this code can block call.
[Can I hang up a call programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23097944/can-i-hang-up-a-call-programmatically-in-android)
but my question is that how to use above code to abort call?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are seeing?  You say you are seeing "this error" but don't describe what the error is.  Is the app crashing?  Do you have logcat output?

Comment: I did, and the content and it still doesn't provide enough detail or answer the questions I just asked.

Comment: OK. please read edit section. I add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot abort the broadcast or programmatically hang up a call.  Telephony control can only be done by the Phone app.  The broadcasts you are registered to receive are informative only: they tell you about state changes but they are not something which is triggering state changes or driving the telephony state machine.

You can intercept/modify *outgoing* calls using the ordered broadcast with action of `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` but there's no public way to intercept an incoming call.